# Merging 2 dataframes in r conditional on dates being within 30d of each other

Tags: r, date, merge, dataframe, conditional-statements

I've run into a questions I can't answer with conditional merging of 2 data frames. Let me describe the data frames (names changed):

- The first, DF1, has a column called 'proceduredate' that contains the date of the procedure per instance (already formatted by as.Date in format %Y-%m-%d).
- The second, DF2, has a variable called 'orderdate' that contains the date of each lab order (also formatted by as.Date in format %Y-%m-%d).

Each dataframe has an identifier (called 'id') for each individual that is used to merge "by" across the two dataframes. I would like to merge the dataframes conditionally to include only the DF2 instances that have an orderdate within 30 days of the proceduredate in DF1. As I understand it, this would look something like:

```
if ([abs(DF1$procdate-DF2$orderdate)<=30]), then{
   merge(DF1,DF2,by="id")
}
```

However, I can't figure out a way to turn this idea into working code. Would you suggest any references or similar prior solutions?

Comment: Why don't you just create an index of what rows that condition is true for and subset the data down to those rows, and then merge?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out the easiest way to do this was to subset the dataframes by another date variable, merge into multiple files, rbind them, then subset the final resulting dataframe by these dates. Next project, will try this in SQL as suggested below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SQL handles this better than (base) R - though I believe there's a way to do it in `data.table`.

```
library(sqldf)
result = sqldf("
  select *
  from DF1 left join DF2 on
    abs(DF1.procdata - DF2.orderdate) <= 30
    AND DF1.id = DF2.id
")
```

I'm not sure this will work with your dates, maybe if they are `Date` class columns. If you provide a reproducible example I'm happy to test.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this on my dataframes, but it does not quite work. I managed a clunkier way of doing this by subsetting the dataframes by another date column, merging, rbinding, and then subsetting the final result. It took longer, but writing a function for it once I considered this method created a reproducible result.

Comment: This answer does seem to answer the question.  The problem is the question, not the answer.  The question did not provide the required minimal self contained reproducible example (including all inputs) but as far as what was presented in the question I think this is the correct answer and should be checked off.